# Can you specify a date range for chartkick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

I'm using chartkick to create some line charts to visualize data in my Rails app. At the moment, however, it shows ALL of the data in my database. Obviously this isn't always ideal. I'd like to give the user the ability to specify the date range of the data shown. I would use the created_at value of the record.

I cannot find any instructions in the documentation on how to do this.

https://github.com/ankane/chartkick.js?files=1

I have created a date picker which will give me a URL like http://localhost:3000/metrics?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search%5Bdate_from%5D=2019-11-01&search%5Bdate_to%5D=2019-11-17&commit=Search

Can chartkicker somehow access those parameters?

In my code a Club has many DailyMetrics, and I've created a metrics action in the clubs controller.

View

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://google.com/jsapi" %>

<div class="row">
  <h1>Metrics</h1>
  <div class="pull-right range-query">
    <%= form_tag metrics_path, method: :get do %>
      <%= text_field_tag 'search[date_from]', @search.date_from %>
      <%= text_field_tag 'search[date_to]', @search.date_to %>
      <%= submit_tag 'Search', class: 'btn search-button' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>

<h3>Total active students</h3>
<%= line_chart @club.daily_metrics.group(:created_at).sum(:total_active_students), library: { animation: { easing: 'easeOutQuad'}} %>
<h3>Lost students</h3>
<%= line_chart @club.daily_metrics.group(:created_at).sum(:lost_students), library: { animation: { easing: 'easeOutQuad'}} %>
<h3>New students</h3>
<%= line_chart @club.daily_metrics.group(:created_at).sum(:new_students), library: { animation: { easing: 'easeOutQuad'}} %>
```

Controller

```rb
def metrics 
  @club = current_club
  @search = MetricSearch.new(params[:search])
  @metrics = @search.scopeContr
end
```

Model for searching for metrics

```rb
class MetricSearch
    attr_reader :date_from, :date_to

    def initialize(params)
        params ||= {}
        @date_from = parsed_date(params[:date_from], 7.days.ago.to_date.to_s)
        @date_to = parsed_date(params[:date_to], Date.today.to_s)
    end

    def scope
        DailyMetric.where('created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', @date_from, @date_to)
    end

    private

        def parsed_date(date_string, default)
            Date.parse(date_string)
        rescue ArgumentError, TypeError
            default
        end
end
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: This is a great article about setting up chartkick. Also loading data in the background https://www.sitepoint.com/graphs-on-rails-chartkick-in-practice/

Answer (score 3):

I posted a link to an great article in your comments, but you can use a gem called [gem 'groupdate'](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate) as well.

```
# Gemfile
gem 'groupdate'
```

Assume your user model `has_many :orders` and you want to find out their spending over the past 6 month:

```
# order.rb
def self.monthly_spending
  group_by_month(:date, last: 6, current: false).sum('orders.total')
end
```

In your view:

```
<%= line_chart current_user.orders.monthly_spending %>
```

Here is another [tutorial how to group by date with chartkick and groupdate gem](https://medium.com/@tdaniel/adding-charts-to-rails-with-chartkick-highcharts-and-groupdate-68f3e718369e).

If you want to preselect a from-to-date for query you can setup a datepicker in your frontend and send the params to your controller

```
def show
  orders = Order.where('created_at > %s AND created_at < %s', params[:start_date], params[:end_date])
end
```

call like above the `group_by` methods on your prefiltered list of orders.

Comment: I  can see how this would allow me to select a specific range of data, however I need the user to be able to select the range from the front end.

Comment: they show here sitepoint.com/graphs-on-rails-chartkick-in-practice how to use date picker in the frontend. Send the params to your controller, query in a simple where-clause, after that gather the data with group_by

Comment: Why not using a datepicker plugin and then you wrap this 2 input fields in a form. The url of the form is your actual view you want to filter. In your controller you can parse the date from a String like I showed the show action. You maybe need `Date.parse(params[:start_date])` or something like this as well